# Recursion in python not reaching correct result

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I have the a problem of wanting to find the number of ways a subset of a list will sum to specific value. However if i run the recursive formula by hand i get a different (correct) value, than with the python code. Am i missing something, or why am i getting different results?

Assume i have a list `b = [2,3,2,1,4]` and a target value of `T = 5`. There will then be 4 subsets that sum to the target value:

```
{b[0], b[1]}
{b[0], b[2], b[3]}
{b[4], b[3]}
{b[1], b[2]}
```

The following code gives a result of 2, but i would like it to return 4.

```
b = [2,3,2,1,4]
def subset_sum(T, idx):
    if T < 0 or idx< 0:
        return 0
    if T == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return subset_sum(T, idx-1) + subset_sum(T-b[idx], idx-1) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(subset_sum(5, 4))
```

edit based on @TomDalton comment:
I tried this and thought that it might be because of the fact that the two if statements are not check simultaneously - therefore in the case where idx = 0 and we subtract the b[0] from the value T, then in the next iteration it will return 0 because it checks if idx < 0 before it checks if T == 0. Although i am unsure of the validity of my guess

Comment: "if i run the recursive formula by hand i get a different (correct) value, than with the python code." - have you tried tracing the code through line by line to see at what point it starts behaving differently to how you expect? The ability to debug code like this is a super important skill as a developer, so practising it whenever possible is a great way to improve!

Comment: @TomDalton. Thanks for your comment. I tried this and thought that it might be because of the fact that the two if statements are not check simultaneously - therefore in the case where idx = 0 and we subtract the b[0] from the value T, then in the next iteration it will return 0 because it checks if idx < 0 before it checks if T == 0. Althouh i am unsure of the validity of my guess

Comment: It could be that! One way to make it easier to debug is to use a smaller example. E.g. what if you have a list of 1 item e.g. [5] and a target of 5? Does it work then? What about a list of 2 items [1, 2], and a target of 3? Or 2? Or a list of 2 items [1,1] with a target of 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your code with extra instrumentation to help track the output, indenting for recursive calls.

You'll notice a critical problem with your counting: when you get the desired total and reach the end of the list, you return `0` instead of `1`.  This prevents you from properly accumulating solutions that achieve the correct total by using the final list element, because you recur past the end of the list *before* you check that you got the right total.  Repair is at the bottom.

```
indent = ""
b = [2,3,2,1,4]

def subset_sum(total, idx):
    global indent
    print(indent + "ENTER", total, idx)
    indent += "  "

    if total < 0 or idx < 0:
        result = 0
    elif total == 0:
        result = 1
    else:
        result = subset_sum(total, idx-1) + subset_sum(total-b[idx], idx-1) 

    indent = indent[2:]
    print(indent + "LEAVE", total, idx, result)
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(subset_sum(5, 4))
```

Output:

```
ENTER 5 4
  ENTER 5 3
    ENTER 5 2
      ENTER 5 1
        ENTER 5 0
          ENTER 5 -1
          LEAVE 5 -1 0
          ENTER 3 -1
          LEAVE 3 -1 0
        LEAVE 5 0 0
        ENTER 2 0
          ENTER 2 -1
          LEAVE 2 -1 0
          ENTER 0 -1
          LEAVE 0 -1 0
        LEAVE 2 0 0
      LEAVE 5 1 0
      ENTER 3 1
        ENTER 3 0
          ENTER 3 -1
          LEAVE 3 -1 0
          ENTER 1 -1
          LEAVE 1 -1 0
        LEAVE 3 0 0
        ENTER 0 0
        LEAVE 0 0 1
      LEAVE 3 1 1
    LEAVE 5 2 1
    ENTER 4 2
      ENTER 4 1
        ENTER 4 0
          ENTER 4 -1
          LEAVE 4 -1 0
          ENTER 2 -1
          LEAVE 2 -1 0
        LEAVE 4 0 0
        ENTER 1 0
          ENTER 1 -1
          LEAVE 1 -1 0
          ENTER -1 -1
          LEAVE -1 -1 0
        LEAVE 1 0 0
      LEAVE 4 1 0
      ENTER 2 1
        ENTER 2 0
          ENTER 2 -1
          LEAVE 2 -1 0
          ENTER 0 -1
          LEAVE 0 -1 0
        LEAVE 2 0 0
        ENTER -1 0
        LEAVE -1 0 0
      LEAVE 2 1 0
    LEAVE 4 2 0
  LEAVE 5 3 1
  ENTER 1 3
    ENTER 1 2
      ENTER 1 1
        ENTER 1 0
          ENTER 1 -1
          LEAVE 1 -1 0
          ENTER -1 -1
          LEAVE -1 -1 0
        LEAVE 1 0 0
        ENTER -2 0
        LEAVE -2 0 0
      LEAVE 1 1 0
      ENTER -1 1
      LEAVE -1 1 0
    LEAVE 1 2 0
    ENTER 0 2
    LEAVE 0 2 1
  LEAVE 1 3 1
LEAVE 5 4 2
2
```

---

**REPAIR**

Merely check for success *before* you check for running off the end of the list:

```
if total == 0:
    result = 1
elif total < 0 or idx < 0:
    result = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you bail out when idx < 0, but without checking first whether maybe T == 0 (which would be a solution). You should first test T == 0:

```
if T == 0:
    return 1
elif T < 0 or idx< 0:
    return 0
else:
    return subset_sum(T, idx-1) + subset_sum(T-b[idx], idx-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered an iterative approach? `itertools.combinations` jumps to mind

> ```
> itertools.combinations(iterable, r)
> ```
>
> Return r length subsequences of elements from
>   the input iterable.
>
> Combinations are emitted in lexicographic sort order. So, if the
>   input iterable is sorted, the
>   combination tuples will be produced in
>   sorted order.

With this, you could do something like:

```
from itertools import combinations

def count_subsets(main_list, target):
    result = 0
    for i in range(len(main_list)):
        sets = combinations(main_list, i)
        result += sum(sum(subset) == target for subset in sets)
    return result
```